# Quoting problems with a string query in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a query using the LIKE operator

```
String camp= nomePesquisa.getValue();
String ql = "select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like ""'%"+camp+"%'"  "";
```

and it gives the following error

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token """", delete this 
     token

Comment: `String ql = "select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like '%" + camp + "%' ";`

Comment: There's a *lot* of quotes going on. Also, beware [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What _scripting_ language are you using? Someone could help you avoid the pitfalls of *SQL Injection Attacks*.  You shouldn't just fix this issue based on answers below, take @Patrick Hofman's advice and use a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

There is a basic mistake that causes all the issues: you don't use parameterized queries. This will a) secure your code against SQL injection, and b) make your SQL easier to write.

In my preferred programming language, C#, it would look like this:

```
"select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like @name"
```

Where `@name` is the name of the parameter you have to pass in.

It seems according to your code you are using Java. [This](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) might help you in that case.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String ql = "select * from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like '%"+camp+"%'+  ";
```

you've put to many quetas, but if you need them to bee in string for some reason, you should escape them `\"`.

P.S. you forgot to type what you wanna select

`Select * FROM table` or `SELECT col1,col2 FROM TABLE`

P.S.S. don't put parameters in query like that, because it is an easy way for [Query Injection](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `"` from that line:

```
String ql = "select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like '%"+camp+"%'+  ";
```

You aren't concatenating anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following to remove the unnecessary quotes:

```
String ql = "select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like '%"+camp+"%'+  ";
```

Also, you can use some `escape` characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write it as

```
String ql = "select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like '%" + camp + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
String ql = "select from pessoal where nome_Pessoa like '%"+camp+"%'+  ";
```

You missed the plus operator